# How do you get the JavaScript stack trace from Nashorn?

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn, scriptengine

I have a script that works just fine in Chrome but crashes on Nashorn with:

> (Error: Namespace "com.cognitect.transit.util" already declared. in  at line number 19664 at column number 6

That error is not very useful, as that line contains:

```
  throw Error('Namespace "' + name + '" already declared.');
```

I need to get a full stack trace from Nashorn, I found [`NashornException.getScriptStackString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/NashornException.html#getScriptStackString-java.lang.Throwable-) but the error Nashorn is generating is of type `javax.script.ScriptException` which gives me an empty string when I call `NashornException.getScriptStackString`.

How do I get an JavaScript stack trace from Nashorn?

I don't want to do it from JavaScript, I want to do it the same way the browser does it, no matter what JS code you are running. A lot of my JS code is third party, it's generated, I cannot modify the thousand of functions I have to print exceptions just in case.

Comment: JavaScript errors generate their stack trace when they're created. You can simply surround your code with a `try/catch` clause and then read the stack no matter where you catch it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Are you referring to try/catch in JavaScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `NashornException` is available as cause of the `ScriptException`:

```
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornException;

...

catch (ScriptException e) {
     if (e.getCause() instance of NashornException) 
         String jsStackTrace = NashornException.getScriptStackString(e.getCause());
}
```